# IARC Rating in Windows Store for older apps

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-store, windows-dev-center

I have read the Age rating documentation, which reads,

```
"The first time you submit an app (or the first time you update an app that was published using the older age rating process), you will be prompted to take a multiple-choice questionnaire to determine your app’s age rating."
```

Does this mean, we have to publish an update for the apps already on windows store, only to submit the IARC rating? Or can we submit the rating, without publishing an update?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you do have to do so.  It only takes a few minutes per app to fill out the questionaire

Comment: Yes just do an update you do not need to update the age rating